# GeoServer OpenLayers and WFS Performance

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs

Currently I'm using GeoServer to dispatch WFS GeoJSON data to OpenLayers using Bbox strategy, the map is made of a WMTS base layer via loaded via MapBox API, although the WFS layers are not so big features are highly concentrated in certain areas and the OpenLayers performance around this areas is a bit slow and laggy, not so bad but it's certainly not the best...

The question is, how could I improve this performance?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: first ask yourself (and then add to the question) why you need to use WFS - could a WMS layer that can be tiled and cached be used instead?